# Preload page content in TabBarView

Tags: flutter

I am currently using a `TabBarView` to display a long list of images (think picture gallery or manga reader).

It seems that each image is only loaded when I start swiping to the new page, i. e. when the edge of the new page becomes visible.

In an Android `ViewPager` we had `setOffscreenPageLimit` to be able to pre-create pages that are still off screen.

Is there a similar functionality in `TabBarView` or would I have to implement the preloading at a lower level, e. g. prefetching the images and caching them locally?

Bonus question: Is `TabBarView` even the correct widget for this use case or is there a more light weight alternative (considering I *do not* want simple scrolling but swiping and self-centering pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we currently have built-in support for preloading tabs in `TabBarView`. You could add it yourself, or using `createLocalImageConfiguration` and `NetworkImage.resolve`, you could cause images to be cached.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!