# Preload a Tab in TabBarView

Tags: dart, flutter

I have my flutter app with 3 tabs. When the app loads, I want it to load all 3 pages and not only the one it will show.
My problem is, that when swiping to my other tab, it takes a second to load the content and then it animates.
What is the proper way to preload a tab for this case?
Or is it done by saving the widget into a variable?

Comment: Is the Widget that is taking long to build or the content that is taking too long to load? Based on what you described, I would pre-load the content and pass it to the widgets instead.

Comment: And how would you do that? I think, that is my main question

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find any solution since then?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I use it like this, it won't take any second to load the tab page.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3, //The number of tabs
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Your tabs page title'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.someIcone),
                text: 'Page-1',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                text: 'Page-2',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                text: 'Page-3',
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageOne(),
            PageTwo(),
            PageThree(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's the way I have it. PageOne(), etc. are Stateful widget, so they are loaded, when needed, right? I tried now to install the app in release mode so that it gets more performance. Here I can't see any loading, too. But if it wasn't only a few Widget in there, wouldn't it take it's time to load, when only loaded, if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Actual answer is that it's not possible to do it the old way

[Preload page content in TabBarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844298/preload-page-content-in-tabbarview/43853043#43853043)